# Updating upload fingerprint in keystore

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, keytool, android-app-signing

We needed to request new keys from Google for signing our Android app due to an administrative issue in the company. We still have the original keystore used to upload the original version of the app to Google Play.

Google issued a new upload key for our app and their email includes an `MD5` and a `SHA1` fingerprint. When I run `keytool -list -keystore myapp.keystore` command against the original keystore, I see the following:

[image]

How do I proceed from here? I'm a bit confused because the original keystore only contains one entry which is the `SHA-256`.

Do I need to generate a new keystore or do I need to import the new `MD5` and `SHA1` and remove the old `SHA-256`? I'd appreciate help with this.

Comment: The process doesn't sound right. They don't generate an upload key, _you_ generate an upload key and share with them the certificate.

Comment: Yes, I did that. In response, they reset my upload keys and sent an email that contains new upload certificate fingerprints i.e. one `MDA5' and one 'SHA1' fingerprints and instructed me to update my keystores. I'm trying to understand what I need to do next.

Comment: When you followed the steps they gave you, you had to generate a keystore. Reference that keystore in your signing configuration e.g. in build.gradle file if you use Android Gradle plug-in. You don't have to do anything with the fingerprints they gave you since they come from what you gave them. Hope that makes sense